# Pycharm New Directory Console Command

Tags: pycharm

I am relatively new to Python programming and I am eager to learn more Python programming. I have a Pycharm project with two packages and I want to use the Python console to make new directories and new python files into the directories using a Python command on the console that Pycharm has built in.

Please could someone tell me the Python console commands to create new directories in the package folders and the commands to create a new Python file for the directories.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What you run in the Python console is simply python code. If you wanted to be able to create directories and files you would use the python code that creates directories and files. Here are the Python Console commands (and the output after entering the command) that would make a directory and create a file.

```
import os
os.getcwd()
'/Users/john/test'
os.mkdir('temp')
open('temp.txt', 'a')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='temp.txt' mode='a' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

`Import os` makes the operating system python functions available

`os.getwd()` shows the current working directory

`os.mkdir('temp')` makes a new directory named temp

`open('temp.txt', 'a')` creates (and opens) a new file named temp.txt

All of the above is done without checking if the directories or files exist.

This is the solution for the Python Console that you asked for, but, you also have access to the Terminal from within PyCharm and the terminal allows you to enter your Bash/DOS commands to make directories. Choose View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal or Alt-F12 to show the terminal window.